# How to find out how many quarters there are beween one quarter and the other in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've created a class called Kwartal (which translates into Quarter) for use in my program:

```
    public sealed class Kwartal {
        private DateTime _poczatekKwartalu;
        private DateTime _koniecKwartalu;
        private int _numerKwartalu;
        private int _rok;

        public Kwartal(int numer, DateTime dataod, DateTime datado) {
            _numerKwartalu = numer;
            _koniecKwartalu = datado;
            _poczatekKwartalu = dataod;
            _rok = dataod.Year;
        }
        public Kwartal() { }

        public int Numer {
            get { return _numerKwartalu; }
            set { _numerKwartalu = value; }
        }
        public DateTime DataPoczatkowa {
            get { return _poczatekKwartalu; }
            set { _poczatekKwartalu = value; }
        }
        public DateTime DataKoncowa {
            get { return _koniecKwartalu; }
            set { _koniecKwartalu = value; }
        }
        public int Rok {
            get { return _rok; }
            set { _rok = value; }
        }
    }
```

It's basically definition for Quarter. Usually i define it like this:

```
Kwartal kwartal1 = new Kwartal(1, new DateTime(year, 1, 1), new DateTime(year, 3, 31));
Kwartal kwartal2 = new Kwartal(2, new DateTime(year, 4, 1), new DateTime(year, 6, 30));
```

Now i was wondering how I can do math on those. For example I've got Quarter1 in 2011 and i then have Quarter3 in 2012. I would like to find out how many quarters are there between Quarter1 and 
Quarter3.

Like `kwartal2 - kwartal1 = 5`

Comment: One tip for future questions, please translate your code to english so we don't have to guess what everything is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your answer, this is what I would do:

```
public static int zwrocRozniceMiedzyKwartalami(Kwartal kwartal1, Kwartal kwartal2) {
    var quartersPerYear = 4;
    var yearDifference = kwartal2.Rok - kwartal1.Rok;
    var differenceQuarters = (yearDifference * quartersPerYear) + (kwartal2.Numer - kwartal1.Numer);
    return differenceQuarters;
}
```

I think this would give you the following answers:

(Year1, Quarter1) - (Year2, Quarter2) = Difference

(2012, 2) - (2011, 1) = (2011 - 2012)*4 + (1 - 2) = -4 + (-1) = -5 => (2011, 1) is 5 quarters before (2012, 2)

(2014, 1) - (2018,3) = (2018 - 2014)*4 + (3 - 1) = 16 + 2 = 18 => (2018,3) is 18 months after (2014,1)

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere do you define the number of quarters in the year - without there being some property/constant set on the `Kwartal` object how can you know what the base value should be for your subtraction operation?

Once you've set that base value, the operation would be reasonably easy, you can create an absolute quarter count, e.g.

```
k.QuarterCount = (k1.year * kwartal.base) + k1.quarter
```

then you have an integer to substract from the other year.

Comment: It's always 4 quarters per year. If it's 4th quarter - 1st quarter thre are 3 quarters between. Also Kwartal.Numer holds the value of which Quarter is it - 1 2 3 or 4.

Comment: yes, I understand that there are four quarters per year, that's the point of calling it quarter ... but where have you coded this?

Comment: well i don't have 4 being set anywhere.

Comment: Check my answers please. This seems to be doing it just fine but maybe I'm over complicating this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **DateDiff** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx), respecting the calendar culture:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void DateDiffSample()
{
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime( 2009, 11, 8, 7, 13, 59 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date1: {0}", date1 );
  // > Date1: 08.11.2009 07:13:59
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime( 2011, 3, 20, 19, 55, 28 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date2: {0}", date2 );
  // > Date2: 20.03.2011 19:55:28

  DateDiff dateDiff = new DateDiff( date1, date2 );
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Quarters: {0}", dateDiff.Quarters );
  // > DateDiff.Quarters: 5
} // DateDiffSample
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define what the result of the calculation should be. Create a matrix/table with some data, and a lot of edge cases, and calculate by hand what the result should be.

Then, you could figure out an algorithm to use to calculate it. And basicly implement this algorithm. And test on your data you made up.

Oh, and then you start thinking about time-zones, daylight saving, etc. And you should read [this blog entry from Jon Skeet](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2010/11/joys-of-datetime-arithmetic.html).

Comment: Time-Zones and Daylight saving isn't my concern. It's one country only and it shouldn't affect Quarters which seem to be static.

Comment: I just used your question to link to Jon Skeets blog (always good for some quick reputation ;-) ). But you are right, ignore my post, until you want the difference in quarters between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you want to achieve

```
DateTime quarter1 = new DateTime(2010, 3, 31); //end date of Q1 as you capture DataKoncowa 
DateTime quarter2 = new DateTime(2011, 3, 31);//end date of Q2 as you capture DataKoncowa 
TimeSpan ts = quarter2 - quarter1; //kwartal2.DataKoncowa  - kwartal1.DataKoncowa
int actualQuarters = ts.Days / (30 *3); //assuming quarter is 90 days
```

This returns 4 .. something like what you expect

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the year / quarters to decimal, and do a little math, you can calculate the difference.

```
class DateTimeQuarter
{
    public DateTimeQuarter(DateTime date)
    {
        Date = date;
        Quarter = date.Month / 4 + 1;
    }
    public static int operator -(DateTimeQuarter lhs, DateTimeQuarter rhs)
    {
        double value = Convert.ToDouble(
            (rhs.Date.Year - lhs.Date.Year)) + (rhs.Quarter / 10.0) - (rhs.Quarter / 10.0);
        int result = 
            (Convert.ToInt32(value) * 4) + Convert.ToInt32(value - Math.Floor(value));
        return result;
    }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTimeQuarter q1 = new DateTimeQuarter(new DateTime(2006, 04, 20));
    DateTimeQuarter q2 = new DateTimeQuarter(new DateTime(2007, 12, 25));

    int quarters = q1 - q2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i ended up doing this. Seems to be working fine. If you've got a better way lemme know :-)

```
    public static int zwrocRozniceMiedzyKwartalami(Kwartal kwartal1, Kwartal kwartal2) {
        int quartersPerYear = 4;
        int differenceQuarters;
        int yearDifference = kwartal2.Rok - kwartal1.Rok;
        if (yearDifference == 0) {
            differenceQuarters = kwartal2.Numer - kwartal1.Numer;
            return differenceQuarters;
        } else if (yearDifference > 0) {
            differenceQuarters = (yearDifference * quartersPerYear) +  (kwartal2.Numer - kwartal1.Numer);
            return differenceQuarters;
        } else if (yearDifference < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return -1;  
    }
```

Comment: Why are you returning -1? A negative difference is still a difference.

Comment: I would discard this as not useful if -1 and not process things further but your solution seems to be better overall.

Comment: One tip for the future is to implement what the function says it does. Returning -1 does not implement a difference, that is why I reacted on it. If it was a compare function it would make sense to return 1, 0 and -1, but you want the difference and a difference can be negative.